# Adobe Connect Add In

Tags: adobe

I am a fairly low level administrator in a large enterprise environment where Adobe Connect is widely deployed.  We are currently upgrading from Windows XP to Windows 7 and the current group policy prevents users from executing files that are not located in C:\ or C:\Program Files.  Fixing group policy is above my authority level but I'm trying to find a way to make the add in work.

Problems are as follows.

1. User is unable to execute the Setup.exe file provided by the Adobe
   Connect Server to install the Add-In.
2. If I run the Add-In installer with my administrator account, two files (listed below) are deployed to my IMO account profile at: C:\users\{Admin
   Profile}\AppData\Roaming\Macromedia\Flash
   Player\www.macromedia.com\bin\connectaddin.exe\

   - connectaddin.exe
   - digest.s
3. If I run the connectaddin.exe program three DLL files are deployed (listed below).  Additionally a Window opens and stays open.  I believe that it can be closed to no ill effect based on conversation [here](http://www.connectusers.com/forums/cucbb/viewtopic.php?id=1404).

   - Connecthook.dll
   - connectsprd.dll
   - meetingconverter.dll
4. Based on reading at the link above, I should be able to deploy these DLLs individually to the same folder in a users profile and have it work.  I've tried this but to no effect. After deploying the files opening a Adobe Connect room still tells me that I need to install the Add-In
5. I've attempted to enable logging for the Add-In by following the directions listed [here](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/606/fd606fac.html#products).  No log file is ever created, which leads me to think that Adobe Connect when loaded in my browser is unable to access the dlls on the computer in order to start the add-in.

Not sure if anyone has advice or a solution but anything to push me along the way would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.